# Wake on lan does not work on second router

Tags: wake-on-lan

I have not good knowledge about hardwares/networking. I would like to use wake on lan feature and really it worked on lan but I m using another wifi router connected with main modem, WOL work fine from main modem but does not work when I try to execute from wifi router.

PC I used to wake up is connected with modem, I think it assumes another network if connected with wifi router.

How I can I configure my wifi router to forward ip/port to first modem?

Gateway for modem: 192.168.1.1
Gateway for wifi router: 192.168.0.1 
PC ip 192.168.1.9

Comment: Wake on LAN normally only works on devices connected to the same subnet. Your Wifi Router is on a different subnet and sends the magic packet to `192.168.0.*` so it won't reach your PC. Consider putting your WiFi router in bridge mode. You may also be able to configure the magic packet to use a wider subnet address. See [Does Wake-on-LAN via WAN needs port forwarding?](http://superuser.com/a/889256) for more information.

Comment: Then can I configure wifi router to use single network.

Comment: That's what bridge mode does.

Comment: Thanks David,  I reconfigured second router and used  as repeter, so as everything on single network so I can wake up my pc even when connected to second router. I cannot perform this when connected to internet, is there any way  without using of public/static  ip?

Answer (score 0):

I reconfigured second router and used as repeter, so as everything on single network so I can wake up my pc even when connected to second router. I cannot perform this when connected to internet.