# Port forwarding not working for port 9

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, port, wake-on-lan

I'm trying to set up my PC to work with Wake on LAN so I set up port forwarding on port 9 on my 
[TP-Link Archer C2 router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57JIt.png). However, when I use [this tool](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) to check whether the port is open, it says it is closed. I created an inbound rule in my firewall that [allows connection through port 9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GS35M.png) and I don't know what else could be causing it to not work properly.

***Note:*** I disabled DHCP so I always have the same IP address.

```
IPv4 Address: 192.168.1.100
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: 192.168.1.1
```

**UPDATE:** I tried binding the MAC address to the IP in the router settings as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/889249/does-wake-on-lan-via-wan-needs-port-forwarding) instead of disabling DHCP via the OS, but I still couldn't wake the PC up using my phone, unless my phone was in the same network when the PC shut down and didn't exit that network.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Wake-on-LAN via WAN needs port forwarding?](https://superuser.com/questions/889249/does-wake-on-lan-via-wan-needs-port-forwarding)

Comment: Another thing to note is that even when you get port forwarding working, you'll need to enter a static ARP mapping on your router so it always knows the IP-to-MAC-address mapping of the machine you are trying to wake.

Comment: That didn't work, but what worked eventually was using a Dynamic DNS hostname rather than the (bound) IP directly. I posted an in-depth answer to describe the steps I took.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like the "Is this port open" checking tools' results are not so relevant after all. What I did in the end to be able to use my phone to turn on my PC remotely, regardless of the network I am in, was to follow the steps described [here](https://www.tp-link.com/ae/faq-922.html) for my router and set up a Dynamic DNS hostname. I'll describe each step here for future reference.

## 1. Enable Wake on LAN from the BIOS

For my ***ASUS ROG motherboard***, this was under *Advanced -> APM -> Enable Power On by PCIE*.

## 2. Allow the Network Adapter to wake up the computer via magic packet

In ***Windows 10***, this can be done by going to *Device Manager -> Network Adapters -> Properties -> Power Management -> Allow this device to wake up the computer (Optional: Only allow a magic packet to wake up the computer)*.

## 3. Change router settings

For a ***TP-Link router***, settings can be accessed by typing [tplinklogin.net](http://tplinklogin.net/) in the address bar. To find out the Network Card's MAC (Physical) Address, open the *Command Prompt* and type in `ipconfig /all`.

### 3.1. IP & MAC binding

[image]

This links the MAC Address of the Network Card to a chosen IP so the router knows to send the packet to the Network Card even when the PC is offline. For a TP-Link router, this is under *IP & MAC Binding -> Binding Settings*.

### 3.2. DHCP Address Reservation

[image]

This ensures that the PC gets assigned the same IP address every time it comes online. For a TP-Link router, this is under *DHCP -> Address Reservation*.

### 3.3. Port Forwarding

[image]

This redirects a request coming from WAN to the chosen IP above. I chose ports 7-9 so in case one doesn't work, I can use another. The default is port 9 for WoL. This setting can be found under *Forwarding -> Virtual Server* for a TP-Link router.

## 4. Pick a Dynamic DNS hostname

I used the [no-ip](https://www.noip.com/) service because it is free, but you have to confirm the hostname every 30 days if you want it to keep working. I downloaded the client and changed the settings so it starts with Windows.

## 5. Set up WoL application

- ***TeamViewer***

  To use TeamViewer to wake up your computer, go to *Extras -> Options -> General -> Wake-on-LAN (Configure...)*, select *Public address* and type in the Dynamic DNS hostname chosen at step 4 and one of the ports you are forwarding to (in my case, 7, 8, or 9 - I chose 9). Make sure the target computer is assigned to your account.
- ***WoL app***

  For a Wake-on-LAN application such as [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.uk.mrwebb.wakeonlan), you will need to enter the MAC address of the target computer as well as the port and hostname.

Another useful link with more details if necessary can be found [here](http://www.acdcelectronics.ro/wake_on_lan_remote_desktop_connection_english.pdf).