# Wake on LAN Issue

Tags: networking, lan, wake-on-lan

I just installed Pulseway Manager and enabled Wake on LAN. It was set up on port 9 UDP. With Pulseway app, I can use it normally when on same wifi. But as soon as I move to other apps on Google Play Store, I just does not work. I just wonder how Pulseway can wake up my server but others can not? Moreover, even pulseway app does not work over WAN. I can confirm that wake on LAN is enabled in network adapter. What might be the problem?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your port forwarding rule? It needs to be set to the [broadcast address of the network](https://superuser.com/questions/889249/does-wake-on-lan-via-wan-needs-port-forwarding).

Comment: @Furty you were absolutely right. I was not entering the broadcast address. Thanks. Please post it as a answer.

Comment: I only answered the WAN part of your question. So please simply remove that part plus add screenshots of Puleseway and at least one non-working app, because i have no idea why only Pulseway works for you.